# Possible to find integers $x,y$ such that $6x+15y=2$?

Tags: divisibility

I know that in general, for two integers $a$ and $b$, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that
\begin{equation}
ax+by=gcd(a,b)
\end{equation}
In this case, let $a=6$ and $b=15$ and let the right-hand-side equal $2$. Do there exist any $x$ and $y$ so that
\begin{equation}
6x+15y=2?
\end{equation}
Note that $2 \ne gcd(6,15)=3$. However, this is what my question comes down to: I know that there DO exist solutions $x$ and $y$ to
\begin{equation}
6x+15y=3
\end{equation}
However, as far as I know, $3$ isn't the ONLY right-hand-side for which this works, is it? In other words, is the greatest common divisor the *only* possible right-hand-side for which this works?

Thanks!

Comment: The number on the R.H.S. must be divisible by the $\gcd$ not necessarily the $\gcd$ itself.

Comment: Take $x=1$ and $y=2$, and you will see that $36$ is a perfectly good solution for the R.H.S. which is not $3$.

Comment: $n$ can be written as $6x+15y$ if and only if $\gcd(6,15)=3$ divides $n$

Comment: $3(2x+5y)=2$ - I don't see how any integer value of $2x+5y$ could be multiplied by $3$ and yield $2$. In other words: $\forall{x,y}\in\mathbb{Z}:2x+5y\in\mathbb{Z}$, but $6x+15y=2\implies3(2x+5y)=2\implies2x+5y=\frac23\not\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $6x + 15 y = 3(2x + 5y)$, the LHS will always be divisible by $3$. Therefor, there cannot be any solution unless the RHS is also divisible by $3$.

Assume now that this is the case, i.e.,
consider the equation $6x + 15y = k \gcd(6,15) = 3 k$, where $k$ is some integer.
As you already have noticed, there exists integers $x_0$, $y_0$ such that
$6x_0 + 15y_0 = 3$. Multiplying both sides by $k$ you obtain that $6(kx_0) + 15(ky_0) = 3 k$. That is, $x = kx_0$ and $y = ky_0$ is a solution to our equation.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We want to find integer $(x,y)$ such that $6x+15y=2$.
Since when $(x,y)=(0,0)$,this is not true.
Since $\gcd(6,15)=3$
So given equation will be $3(2x+5y)=2$.
Since term in bracket can only be an integer or zero,
Hence $3(2x+5y)$ is multiple of $3$ or $0$.
Since $2$ is not a multiple of $3$, so no solution with $x,y$ both integer is possible,
I think you can generalize from here

Comment: "integer or zero": zero is also an integer. "multiple of $3$ or $0$": $0$ is also a multiple of $3$. You are not dealing with separate cases here. It makes your proof less elegant.

Comment: I have use 0 as special case in lot of problem,old habits doesn't die ;)